# How to unnest list of dictionary in the dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe, df as follow.

| id | name | code | date | Additional info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | shirt | xyz123 | 2022-01-01 | [{'name': 'phone', 'code': 'ph123'}, {'name': 'car', 'code': 'cx2022'}, {}] |
| 02 | bike | bk001 | 2022-12-10 | [{}, {}, {}] |
| 03 | phone | ph987 | 2023-02-10 | [{'name': 'shirt', 'code': 'xyz456'}] |

I would like to unnest the additional info column and assigned values of each json into name and code columns respectively. The expected output is shown as follow. The new added rows are bolded after being unnested additional info column. In the final output, the additional info column is removed.

**Expected DataFrame output:**

| id | name | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | shirt | xyz123 | 2022-01-01 |
| **01** | **phone** | **ph123** | **2022-01-01** |
| **01** | **car** | **cx2022** | **2022-01-01** |
| 02 | bike | bk001 | 2022-12-10 |
| 03 | phone | ph987 | 2023-02-10 |
| **03** | **shirt** | **xyz456** | **2023-02-10** |

Can someone help me solve this challenge?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), convert the dictionaries to columns with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to the original DataFrame:

```
s = df['Additional info'].explode()

out = pd.concat([df[['id', 'name', 'code', 'date']], 
                 df[['id', 'date']].join(pd.json_normalize(s)
                                           .set_axis(s.index).dropna(),
                                         how='inner')
                ]).sort_index(kind='stable')
```

Variant that only require to know the column to unnest:

```
cols = 'Additional info'

s = df[cols].explode()
tmp = df.drop(columns=col)

out = pd.concat([tmp, 
                 pd.json_normalize(s)
                   .set_axis(s.index).dropna()
                   .combine_first(tmp)
                ]).drop_duplicates().sort_index(kind='stable')
```

Output:

```
   id   name    code        date
0   1  shirt  xyz123  2022-01-01
0   1  phone   ph123  2022-01-01
0   1    car  cx2022  2022-01-01
1   2   bike   bk001  2022-12-10
2   3  phone   ph987  2023-02-10
2   3  shirt  xyz456  2023-02-10
```

Comment: Hi, If the  type of value in the "Additional info" is string, how do I unnest the column ?

Comment: @Peter: first convert to dictionaries with `import ast ; df['Additional info'] = df['Additional info'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score 0):

## Unnest the Additional info column, explode the column into relevant rows

```
df_unnested = df.explode('Additional info')

# Extract the relevant columns
df_final = df_unnested[['id', 'name', 'code', 'date']]
```

Comment: It's not giving correct solution

Comment: The above solution is not working.