# How to split pandas column dictionary into new columns and rows (explode not working)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to split the data from one of the column in json / dict format to new rows and column.
e.g. Input

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | blue | [{city: "Manhattan", job_type: "PERM", sal_gp: 0d-1, age: 3.4}, {city: "Dallas", job_type: "TEMP", sal_gp: 0d-1, age: 1.4}] |
| jack | gold | [{city: "San Diego", job_type: "TEMP", sal_gp: 0d-1, age: 5.44}] |

expected output

| Column A | Column B | city | job_type | sal_gp | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | blue | Manhattan | PERM | 0d-1 | 3.4 |
| john | blue | Dallas | TEMP | 0d-1 | 1.4 |
| Jack | gold | San Diego | TEMP | 0d-1 | 5.44 |

output of df.to_dict('tight'):

```
{'index': [0,1], 'columns': ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'], 'data': [['john','blue',[{city: "Manhattan", job_type: "PERM", sal_gp: 0d-1, age: 3.4}, {city: "Dallas", job_type: "TEMP", sal_gp: 0d-1, age:
1.4}]],'jack', 'gold',  [{city: "San Diego", job_type: "TEMP", sal_gp: 0d-1, age: 5.44}]], 'index_names':[None], 'column_names': [None] }
```

This is not a duplicate question  as [How to unnest list of dictionary in the dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472450/how-to-unnest-list-of-dictionary-in-the-dataframe-column)
As you can see the data formatting is different. Json loads, pandas explode will not work as this is not a standard python or json formatting of data.
I already tried json loads and pandas explode but it is not working.
I am not sure but is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: Your input if ambiguous. Assuming `df` the input, please [edit] your question with the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`

Comment: Is the data used to create the first data frame json? If so, it is easier to to work with the json data rather than trying to parse it out when in a data frame.

Comment: the dataframe is is the source of data for me so can't work on the json data before entering into the datatframe. I have csv .

Comment: Then provide the csv

Comment: updated the question with the df.to_dict('tight') output.

Comment: OK, then `explode` and `join` the output of `json_normalize`

Comment: `out = df.explode('Column C', ignore_index=True).pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.json_normalize(d.pop('Column C'))))`

Comment: And if you have strings: `df.assign(**{'Column C': lambda d: d['Column C'].apply(ast.literal_eval)}).explode('Column C', ignore_index=True).pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.json_normalize(d.pop('Column C'))))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal reproducible example (that you should have provided)

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['john', 'jack'], 'B':['blue','gold'], 'C':[[{'city':'Manhattan', 'job':'perm'}, {'city':'Dallas', 'job':'temp'}], [{'city':'San Diego', 'job':'temp'}]]})
```

I've simplified a bit the names and the fields, since this is what "minimal" examples are. And it is reproducible, because anybody can copy and paste the code and try it at home.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | john | blue | [{'city': 'Manhattan', 'job': 'perm'}, {'city': 'Dallas', 'job': 'temp'}] |
| 1 | jack | gold | [{'city': 'San Diego', 'job': 'temp'}] |

The thing is, column C needs two layer of "expanding". One for the array, then another for the dicts in that array.

Let's start by exploding arrays

```py
dfc=df.explode('C').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Gives

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | john | blue | {'city': 'Manhattan', 'job': 'perm'} |
| 1 | john | blue | {'city': 'Dallas', 'job': 'temp'} |
| 2 | jack | gold | {'city': 'San Diego', 'job': 'temp'} |

So, half of the job is done: one row for each value in `C` array. Rest the expanding of fields of dict.

We can find how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas)

```py
dfc.join(pd.json_normalize(dfc.C)).drop(columns='C')
```

`json_normalize` creates columns with fields of `C`. `join` add those new columns. And `drop` drops the `C` column now that we no longer need it

Result is:

|  | A | B | city | job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | john | blue | Manhattan | perm |
| 1 | john | blue | Dallas | temp |
| 2 | jack | gold | San Diego | temp |

Comment: Thanks @chrslg for editing the question too. The issue is if you see my input the key value pairs in the json data are not in right format and maybe that is the reason my code fails. 
e.g you wrote as 'city': 'manhattan' but in my input it is city:'manhattan' . the quotes are missing .

Comment: Oh. What are those data then? This is neither legal python, nor legal json. You would have to invent some parser (I think it is legal javascript, but I am not sure there are any javascript parser)

Comment: this is part of sql table, i am dumping it to csv  as I was thinking explode may help to clean the data

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

explode & apply

```
df1 = df.explode('Column C', ignore_index=True)
df1[['Column A', 'Column B']].join(df1['Column C'].apply(pd.Series))
```

output:

```
    Column A    Column B    city        job_type    sal_gp  age
0   john        blue        Manhattan   PERM        0d-1    3.40
1   john        blue        Dallas      TEMP        0d-1    1.40
2   jack        gold        San Diego   TEMP        0d-1    5.44
```

If the results are not the same, please provide your example in code.

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Column A': ['john', 'jack'], 'Column B': ['blue', 'gold'], 
         'Column C': [[{'city': "Manhattan", 'job_type': "PERM", 'sal_gp': '0d-1', 'age': 3.4}, 
                       {'city': "Dallas", 'job_type': "TEMP", 'sal_gp': '0d-1', 'age': 1.4}], 
                      [{'city': "San Diego", 'job_type': "TEMP", 'sal_gp': '0d-1', 'age': 5.44}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Intermediate**

`df1`

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
0   john    blue    {'city': 'Manhattan', 'job_type': 'PERM', 'sal...
1   john    blue    {'city': 'Dallas', 'job_type': 'TEMP', 'sal_gp...
2   jack    gold    {'city': 'San Diego', 'job_type': 'TEMP', 'sal...
```

Comment: the issue is in the input . there is a slight change in the input and that is the reason explode function is not working . 
e.g your input is {'city': 'Manhattan', 'job_type': 'PERM',
but actual input is {city: 'Manhattan', job_type: 'PERM',